# angular column virtualization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

We are currently working with ng Grid.
The grid that we are working on has around 30 rows, however, 200 columns.

I have read that ng grid supports column virtualization and Row virtualization where by row virtualization is on by default if rows > 50  (I realize that this thresh hold can be configured by using virtualizationThreshold)

However,  what i cant find is how to enable column virtualization. Is this on by default, or is it tied into virtualizationThreshold where by its only enabled if rows > 50?

appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

There is the `enableColumnHeavyVirt` property that is disabled by default. You have to set it to `true` in your `gridOptions` before you can use it. [ngGrid Configuration Options](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options)

Comment: Thank you,  we have just tried that, yet now, we are seeing no results? it seems to load the page faster, and also displays the scroll bars as tho data is there, but nothing can actually be seen? are there any additional settings that are needed?